# The image you are attempting to upload doesn't fit into the allowed dimensions. problem

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

i am using codeigniter 3.1.10 and i am use upload library and i got some error

this is my form

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo base_url() ?>addimg">
<input id="file-upload" type="file"  accept="image/*" name='book_image' onchange="preview_image(event)"/>
<button class="btn black">Add img</button>
</form>
```

this is my addimage controller

```
$config['upload_path']          = './school_book_imgs/';
        $config['allowed_types']        = '*';
        $config['max_size']             = 1024;
        $config['max_width']            = 768;
        $config['max_height']           = 1024;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        if ($this->upload->do_upload('book_image')) {   
            $form_data = $this->input->post();

            $data = $this->upload->data();
            $path = $data['raw_name'].$data['file_ext'];
            $form_data['book_image'] = "school_book_imgs/".$path;
            $form_data['user_id'] = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
            $this->load->model('savedata');
            if ($this->savedata->addschoolbook($form_data)){
                return redirect(base_url()."dashboard");
            }
            else{
                $this->load->view('404');
            }

        }else{
            $error = $this->upload->display_errors();
            // print_r($this->upload->data());
            $this->load->view('addschoolbook',compact('error'));
            $this->load->view('footer');
        }

    }
```

i allowed all domail and i add manualy

```
$config['allowed_types']        = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';
```

but i got same error every time

```
The image you are attempting to upload doesn't fit into the allowed dimensions.
```

please tell me solution

Comment: Have you tried not specifying dimensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this error :
The image you are attempting to upload doesn't fit into the allowed dimensions

means that you are telling codeigniter to not accept or allow any picture dimensions bigger than 768x1024, max_width = 768 and max_height = 1024

just give higher dimensions example

```
$config['max_width']            = 6000; // 6000px you can set the value you want
$config['max_height']           = 6000; // 6000px
```

Also your are setting accepted size to only 1mb and less, so any picture bigger than 1024kb= 1mb will not pass so change that too to a bigger size example:

```
$config['max_size']             = 10024; // 10mb you can set the value you want
```